# How can i repeat a script?

Tags: awk, csh

i've search for command or solution to repeat a script after n times but i can't find it.
This is my rusty script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
rm -rf result120
rm -rf result127
rm -rf result126
rm -rf result125
rm -rf result128
rm -rf result129
rm -rf result122
rm -rf output
rm -rf aaa
### Get job id from user name
foreach file ( `cat name` )
        echo `bjobs -u $file | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+/ {print $1}' >> aaa`
        echo "loading"
end
### Read in job id
foreach file ( `cat aaa` )
    echo `bjobs -l $file >> result120`
    echo "loading"
end
### Get pattern in < >
awk '{\
gsub(/                     /,"",$0)}\
BEGIN {\
RS =""\
FS=","\
}\
{\
s=1\
e=150\
if ($1 ~/Job/){\
for(i=s;i<=e;i++){\
    printf("%s", $(i))}\
}\
}' result120 > result126
grep -oE '<[^>]+>' result126 > result125
### Get Current Work Location
awk '$1 ~ /<lsf_login..>/ {getline; print $1}' result125 >result122 #result127
### Get another information and paste it with CWD
foreach file1 ( `cat aaa` )
    echo `bjobs $file1 >> result128`
    echo "getting data"
end
awk '$1 ~ /JOBID/ {getline; printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-20s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' result128 >> result129
paste result129 result122 >> output
### Summary
awk '{count1[$2]++}{count2[$4]++}{count3[$3]++}\
END{\
print "\n"\
print "##########################################################################"\
print "There are: ", NR " Jobs"\
for(name in count1){ print name, count1[name]}\
print "\n"\
for(queqe in count2){ print queqe, count2[queqe]}\
print "\n"\
for(stt in count3){ print stt, count3[stt]}\
}' output >> output
```

And my desire is run it again per 15 minutes to get report. Someone told me use Wait but i've searched for it in man wait and can't find any 
useful example. That's why i need yours help to solve this problem. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run the script every 15 mins

```
while true; do ./script.sh; sleep 900; done
```

or set a `cron` job or use `watch`

For `c shell` you have to write

```
while (1)
   ./script.sh
   sleep 900
end
```

but why use csh since you have `bash`?  Double check the syntax, since I don't remember it much anymore...

Comment: so i add the whole line "While true...." to the last line of the script?
or run it at command windows?
i do both but it say that "while: Expression Syntax"
can you give me an examble of watch? 
my script file is script.csh and i want to run it every 15 mins

Comment: my company they only use csh :(

Answer (score 1):

Following @karakfa answer, you have basically 2 options.

1) Your first option, even if you use a `sleep` implements a kind of **busy-waiting** strategy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), this stragegy uses more CPU/memory than your second option (the cron approach) because you will have in memory your processus footprint even if it is actually doing nothing.

2) On the other hand, in the cron approach your processus will only appear while doing useful activities.

Just Imagine if you implement this kind of approach for many programs running on your machine, a lot of memory will be consume by processus in waiting states, it will also have an impact (memory/CPU usage) on the scheduling algorithm of your OS since it will have more processes in queue to manage.

Therefore, I would absolutely **recommend the cron/scheduling** approach.

Anyway,your cron daemon will be running in background whether you add the entry or not in the crontab, so why not adding it?

Last but not least, imagine if your busy-waiting processus is killed for any reason, if you go for the first option you will need to restart it manually and you might lose a couple of monitoring entries.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks Allan 
i'm searching for crontab to run in background per n time.
can you give me a simple example of crontab?

Comment: I would recommend reading this link, you will find all the information for the set up! Good luck

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: oh lord. 
i test crontab but it seem like the script doesn't work
my crontab is 52 13 * * * /home/u/duy/script.csh but the script doesn't work as well? it can't read the input file

Comment: just to add a quick note to correct a misconception.  Any self-respecting OS will implement sleep without busy-waiting; so it's not a performance concern.  But agree with monitoring and serviceability issues.